# Serialized data in Wordpress form is "serialized" again when saved in mysql

Tags: wordpress, serialization, phpmyadmin

I have a challenge with the way data is stored from Wordpress into mysql.
I'm new to Wordpress - but I'm trying to combine different plugins to achieve a specific functionality on a website.

Plugin #1 uses a specific type of post and some metadata - the plugin works great.

Plugin #2 can create posts of custom types and with custom metadata from the frontend. A flexible and great plugin.

My intention is to use plugin #2 to create posts from the frontend for plugin #1, which requires that some specific metadata contains specific values (otherwise the data are interpretted wrong). These values are saved with hidden inputfields in a form.

My challenge is that a value (which is serialized) is kind of serialized again. The value is a:1:{i:0;s:3:"198";}
Plugin #2 handles it well (as the data is shown correct in front- and backend of the plugin) - BUT in myPhpAdmin I can see that the data is saved differently s:20:"a:1:{i:0;s:3:"198";}"; - and hence that value cannot be understood by plugin #1.

I'm thinking of two options:

1. change something so s:xx: isn't added to the value(-s)
2. make the frontend form/plugin save the data in a serialized way so the value gets the correct format.

Any recommendations? - can I in anyway achieve my functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

> s:20:"a:1:{i:0;s:3:"198";}";

value is being serialized twice. You can check the plugin source code to see why the plugin serializing same value twice and if can prevent it than both plugin can share same data.